# Python, How can I get frames with a stride, such as 500, quickly?

Tags: python, video, ffmpeg

I'd like to get a lot of frames from videos, like movies, and set the stride as 500 or much more. I have tried imageio as following, but it's slow. Is there any methods quicker?

```
filename='./alita.mkv'
vid=imageio.get_reader(filename, 'ffmpeg')
cnt = 0 
for i, im in enumerate(vid):
    if i % 500 == 0:
        cnt += 1
        cv2.imwrite('./alita/alita_{}.jpg'.format(cnt), im)
```

BTW, what's the type of the `vid` get by `imageio.get_reader()`, it is not a list?

Comment: Have you tried CV2 instead?

Comment: You can answer your additional question with a simple `type(vid)`.